# Move down grid column when narrowing window in WinUI

Tags: xaml, winui-3

I have a GridView with two columns with static width in XAML. But second column hiding off out of window when window narrowing. How to make second column moving under first column and not hide it out of window? Thanks.

```xml
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- first column-->
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <ScrollViewer>   
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
               <!-- listview -->
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
    <!-- second column -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5,10,0,0">
                <!-- listview -->
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Updated: added source code

Comment: Can you post minimal reproducible code?

Comment: I added grid code. Two columns and some listview inside it

Comment: [Is Grid the right control?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/layout/layouts-with-xaml#layout-properties) You may look for [GridView](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/a6960580998f000f2d1b7ef5b838317fce687f5c/WinUIGallery/ControlPages/GridViewPage.xaml#L89) as @AndrewKeepCoding answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a control called [GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/listview-and-gridview):

```xml
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid
                MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"
                Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.Items>
        <Button Content="Item 1" />
        <Button Content="Item 2" />
    </GridView.Items>
</GridView>
```